How to implement drag and drop between buttons and dynamic 2D array rows using Angular CDK?
I’m working on an Angular component where I want to drag and drop items from a set of alphabet buttons into different rows of a 2D array (slotButtons). Each row should act as an independent drop target, and I want to be able to drop multiple items into different rows.
Here’s a simplified version of my setup:
I have an array alphabet that contains buttons representing alphabet items (e.g., ['a', 'b', 'c', ...]).
I have a 2D array slotButtons where each sub-array represents a row, and I want to drop alphabet items into these rows.
HTML
<div class="container">
  <!-- Alphabet Buttons -->
  <div cdkDropList class="alphabet-list" [cdkDropListData]="alphabet" (cdkDropListDropped)="onAlphabetDrop($event)">
    <button *ngFor="let letter of alphabet" cdkDrag>{{ letter }}</button>
  </div>

  <!-- Slot Buttons -->
  <div *ngFor="let slot of slotButtons; let i = index">
    <div cdkDropList [cdkDropListData]="slotButtons[i]" (cdkDropListDropped)="onDrop($event, i)" class="slot">
      <div *ngFor="let item of slot" cdkDrag>{{ item }}</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

Functionality i wish to include
How can I correctly implement drag-and-drop functionality for:
Dragging alphabet items into the rows of slotButtons.
Moving items between different rows within slotButtons?
# Solution #
    <div cdkDropListGroup>
    <div class="example-container">
        <h2>Slot buttons</h2>
        @for (items of slotButtons; track items) {
        <div cdkDropList [cdkDropListData]="items" class="example-list" (cdkDropListDropped)="drop($event)">
            @for (item of items; track item) {
            <div class="example-box" cdkDrag [cdkDragData]="item">{{item}}</div>
            }
        </div>
        }
    </div>
    <div class="example-container">
        <h2>ALPHABETS</h2>
        <div cdkDropList [cdkDropListData]="alphabet" class="example-list" (cdkDropListDropped)="drop($event)">
            @for (item of alphabet; track item) {
                <div class="example-box" cdkDrag [cdkDragData]="item">{{item}}</div>
            }
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

Component
slotButtons = [['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'], ['E', 'F', 'G', 'H']];
alphabet = [...Array.from({ length: 26 }, (_, i) => String.fromCharCode(65 + i))];

  drop(event: CdkDragDrop<string[]>) {
    if (event.previousContainer === event.container) {
      moveItemInArray(event.container.data, event.previousIndex, event.currentIndex);
    } else {
      transferArrayItem(
        event.previousContainer.data,
        event.container.data,
        event.previousIndex,
        event.currentIndex,
      );
    }
  }

Changes :
I have added cdkDropListGroup, By using cdkDropListGroup, it ensure that all cdkDropList elements within the group can participate in coordinated drag-and-drop behaviors. For example, you can drag an item from one list and drop it into another list within the same group.
